# Getting a specific joint position in C++ and kinect

Tags: c++, kinect

How do I get the position data of a specific joint (i.e. hip joint) from Kinect using C++? I spent hours reading docs and source code but I can't figure out how to specify the joint I would like to get the data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131025.aspx#ID4EIH) which explains how to lookup the right joint in the `Skeleton Stream`.

For example, to get the hip joint, you would use the `NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_HIP_CENTER` index.